# Understanding Linux process management

Tags: linux, kernel

I try to understand the internals around the Linux kernel, the process management and the context switch around the processes. As far as I understand the tutorials (from this community, IBM, and so on) the kernel is loaded by the bootloader after the power button is pressed. It then starts the scheduler and creates the final init process which is responsible for starting all other processes.

So after some time, a context switch occurs. During this context switch, the kernel looks at the page table for the new process and load it (if necessary) into the TLB of the MMU. Does the kernel load the whole page table (so for 4 GB of virtual memory on a 32-bit system) into the MMU? And how does this table swap works, because as I understand it, the top 1 GB of memory will be present and not swapped out during all processes, because this is the kernel memory? Does the page tables for all processes contain a direct mapping for the top 1 GB of memory, so that the top 1 GB of virtual memory is directly mapped into the top 1 GB of physical memory?

Is there some kind of documentation of how this context switch works because I don´t find any documents who explain this for noobs like me.

Comment: Init, or say PID=1, yes, started by the kernel, but not all process are forked from it. Eg. shell running in xfce4-terminal is forked directly from xfce4-terminal, not init. After some time, fork() return to userspace, now the page table related to the new process has been built. The page table is in the memory, this is determined by CPU not kernel. Read x86 memory management on textbooks, don't simply imagine it. The kernel is loaded into physical memory, but address depends, then it's mapped into virtual memory space of processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each process has its own set of page pages, spanning the low 3 GB on 32-bit x86 machines. The top 1 GB on 32-bit machines is common to all processes, and is not accessible from user space. The top 1 GB is reserved for the kernel, and originally contained a mapping of the whole physical RAM offset by 3 GB. This means physical memory address 0 is visible at virtual address 0xc0000000, physical memory address 1 is visible at address 0xc0000001, and so on. When memory sizes outgrew the 1 GB limit, the excess physical memory started to be accessed via a "highmem" window.

On x86-64, the upper half of the address space is reserved for the kernel, the lower half for user space. Note that current hardware does not allow use of the whole 64-bit address space: typically only 48 address bits are usable, the upper 16 bits must be either all zeroes or all ones. (The exact number of usable bits varies depending on the CPU model.)

At a context switch, the user space part of the mapping is replaced with the new process's mapping, but the kernel part stays the same. The whole 4 GB memory space is not mapped, only the parts that are actually used. This allows for a much smaller page table tree. The initial mapping is determined by the ELF file containing the program to be run. The page tables are modified as needed when new memory is allocated dynamically, mapped using `mmap`, or by automatically extending the stack.

The scheduler is not "started", since it is not a separate process. The kernel reschedules processes when the running process needs to wait for input or some other event, or when the current process has used up its time slice. Each process is in one of several states, like waiting for some event, ready to run, or running. When the kernel does a reschedule, it examines the list of ready to run processes, and chooses one (per CPU) to run next.

Also, the Translation Lookaside Buffer (TLB) is not loaded directly by the kernel (on x86 processors). Software only modifies page tables, and the hardware automatically fills the entries in the TLB as needed at runtime. The TLB can be flushed by software; this needs to be done at a context switch.

A few books have been written on the Linux kernel internals ("Understanding the Linux Kernel", for example), but most of them are quite old by now. But, even if they are not good references anymore, many of them do provide sill relevant information, but you have to keep in mind that a lot has changed.